# Spring Boot trace Actuator is logging HTTP body which contains password in outbound request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j, spring-boot-actuator

```
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.set("username", "user1");
        map.set("password", "password1");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.ALL));

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> obj;

        obj = makeRESTCall(api, entity, HttpMethod.POST);
```

I inherited this Spring Boot project and I am trying to improve logging. I wanted to log all incoming requests and the corresponding responses. I decided to try using the httptrace Actuator which is built into SB. This Actuator is working well however it seems to log every HTTP request, both incoming and outgoing.

In the above snippet my code is making a POST request and the username/password are included in the HTTP body. The Actuator catches this outbound request and logs the password in plain text.

I do not want any sensitive information appearing in the logs.

Is there something I can change in the httptrace Actuator config so it only logs incoming requests?

Perhaps I am better off creating a custom Filter to only log the incoming request and corresponding response? I don't quite care to log the outgoing requests.

Logging is done with log4j-to-slf4j btw

Answer (score 0):

If your logging framework supports MDC, then set a flag in the MDC before the call and remove it after the call. Configure your logging framework with a filter to skip logging of the events with the flag set in MDC.